# How to redirect all subdomain URL to main domain using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

My old blog URL is `http://www.blog.example.com/`

My new blog URL is `https://example.com/`

I want to know how can I redirect all my old blog URLs to my new blog URLs.

For example, I want to redirect this URL:

```
http://www.blog.example.com/excellent-examples-forms-web-design
```

to

```
https://example.com/excellent-examples-forms-web-design
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. mod_rewrite is required in order to check the requested hostname.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference matches `example.com` in the preceding *CondPattern* (this simply saves repetition).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid potential caching issues.